# Keep counter in txt file

Tags: c, file

I am trying to keep a conter in txt file, I write a function and when I call the fuction, function should read the txt after, it should increment and write file.

In my txt ("test.txt") there is only one character. It is "0".

Code is here:

```
void readAndwrite(){

    int total = 23;
    FILE *fread, *fwrite;
    fread = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    fwrite = fopen("test.txt","w");
    fscanf(fread,"%d",&total);
    fclose(fread);
    ++total;

    fprintf(fwrite ,"%d",total);
    fclose(fwrite);



}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{


    readAndwrite();
    readAndwrite();
    readAndwrite();
    readAndwrite();
    readAndwrite();
    readAndwrite();


    return 0;
}
```

Why this is not working?

Comment: You open the same file twice, open it once but with "rw"

Comment: I tryed, Reading is correct but writing do not working. ( fprintf(fread,"%d",total);)

Comment: Try getting the result of the fprintf call. Perhaps it is returning an error code.

Comment: What is your intended output? What are you expecting the file to hold as a value?

Comment: Calling your variables `fread` and `fwrite` might be confusing.  There are also *functions* with those names, and they're used to read and write data on `FILE *` pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can open twice but not in same time because the "w" flag destroy contents, so:

```
void readAndwrite(){    
    int total = 23;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if(!f) {
        perror("File opening failed");
    }
    else{
        fscanf(f,"%d",&total);
        fclose(f);
        printf("%d\n", total);
        ++total;
        f = fopen("test.txt","w");
        fprintf(f ,"%d",total);
        fclose(f);
    }
}
```

If you want to read/write in same time take a look to the [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) and "w+" flag